# How can I make a Vector that goes to a position?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a spritenode that runs an action to go to a position. In the future I want to have the spritenode collide with other nodes in the way to stop it from reaching that position. So I thought of an impulse. But how do I make a vector that moves to a position?

Comment: You can apply CGVectorMake to make a sprite move in a specific direction but not to make it start moving from point A and stop at point B without setting the velocity back to 0.

Comment: Yeah I think im going to use field gravity to achieve the same